# ORA-14074: partition bound must collate higher than that of the last partition 14074

Tags: oracle

I am getting this error.

> ORA-14074: partition bound must collate higher than that of the last
> partition
> 14074.

I am unable to solve this error.

I am trying to adding partition to the table.

Comment: Please provide reproducible example. Or at least what you are doing and what is your current partitions of that table.

Comment: [**ORA-14074** partition bound must collate higher than that of the last partition](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e12700.htm#1656)
**Cause**: Partition bound specified in ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION statement did not collate higher than that of the table's last partition, which is illegal.

**Action**: Ensure that the partition bound of the partition to be added collates higher than that of the table's last partition.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The limit value for the partition you're adding is lower that the highest limit already in the table:

```
create table t (
  c1 int
) partition by range ( c1 ) (
  partition p1 values less than ( 9 ),
  partition p2 values less than ( 99 )
);

alter table t 
  add partition p3 values less than ( 0 );
  
ORA-14074: partition bound must collate higher than that of the last partition
```

0 < 99 => you can't add the partition. If you want a partition with this upper bound you'll need to split an existing partition.

You can find the current highest value by querying `*tab_partitions` and getting the `high_value` for the partition with the max `partition_position`

```
with rws as (
  select table_name, partition_position, high_value, 
         row_number () over ( 
           partition by table_name 
           order by partition_position desc 
         ) rn
  from   user_tab_partitions
)
select table_name, high_value 
from   rws
where  rn = 1;

TABLE_NAME HIGH_VALUE                                                                      
---------- ----------
T          99
```